# How to correctly parse an integer in PHP?

Tags: php, casting, int

I can use `intval`, but according to the documentation:

> Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the
>   leftmost characters of the string. The common rules of integer casting
>   apply.

... and the value to parse can be `0`, that is I will not able to distinguish between zero and a `string`.

```php
$value1 = '0';
$value2 = '15';
$value3 = 'foo'; // Should throw an exeption
```

Real question is: how can I parse the string and distinguish between a `string` that cast to `0` and a zero itself?

Comment: How conservative do you need to be? intval works fine, but if you expect the string to contain non-numeric values and you need to PRESERVE the numeric values, you'll want to run it through a preg_replace first.

Comment: @cale_b string should be all numeric to be casted.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In the code below, `$int_value` will be set to `null` if `$value` wasn't an actual numeric string (base 10 and positive), otherwise it will be set to the integer value of `$value`:

```
$int_value = ctype_digit($value) ? intval($value) : null;
if ($int_value === null)
{
    // $value wasn't all numeric
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not benchmarked against the ctype_digit(), but I think the following is a nice option. Of course it depends on the exact behavior you expect.

```
function parseIntOrException($val) {
  $int = (int)$val;
  if ((string)$int === (string)$val) {
    throw \Exception('Nope.');
  }
  return $int;
}
```

http://3v4l.org/Tf8nh

```
1       1
'2'     2
'3.0'   false
4.0     4
5       5
```